# Lenovo Ideapad S210

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, touchpad, lenovo, touchscreen

"Try without install" on 13.10 gives me a wonderful experience with the touchscreen (much better than windows8) but the mousepad and keyboard don't work!!! How can I fix this? I don't want to install until I'm sure everything is going to work. Another question: when going forward to the install program, it doesn't recognize windows8 on it, it says there are no OS on the machine. That doesn't scare me so much, I'm planning to create a separate partition using win8 and then just install on that, but want to ask: anyone with more experience/knowledge on this thinks this might work, or is it a completely wrong idea?

Answer (score 1):

I braced myself and installed anyway, even without the mouse and keyboard working hoping that updates would fix it: they did. Just turn on "download updates" before start installing and you'll be fine!